# Model store with different column than primaryKey

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I have this Laravel/OctoberCMS Model to interface with my ExchangeModel.

It's a one sided relationship with my ExchangeModel.
Currently it stores in the Customer database table via ExchangeModel.id. But i'd like it to store as ExchangeModel.currencyISO, which is a 3 letter country code.

What do I need to setup in the relation to get laravel to store it via the other field I try to define via otherKey or key instead of the primaryKey(id)?

```
<?php namespace PhunTime\Client\Models;

use Model;
/**
 * Customer Model
 */
class Customer extends Model {
    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'CUSTOMER';
    public $primaryKey = 'customerNumber';

    /**
     * @var array Relations
     */
    public $belongsTo = ['currency' => ['PhunTime\ExchangeRate\Models\ExchangeModel',
            'key' => 'currencyISO',// EUR,USD,YEN
            'otherKey' => 'currencyISO'

    ]];
}
```

Clarification of the structure:

```
- Customer
   - id
   - name
   - currency(varchar(3)) <-- relation

 - ExchangeModel
   - id
   - currencyISO
```

Currently the ExchangeModel.id gets stored in Customer.currency

I want ExchangeModel.currencyISO to be stored in Customer.currency
Customer.currency is already a varchar field suitable to accept it.

Currently if I specify `type:relation` in fields.yaml it stores it by `ExchangeModel.id` no matter what I specify how it should store it. use of otherKey, foreignKey, key, nothing helps changing octobers mind.

Currently i'm using a `type: dropdown` that i populate via `getcurrencyOptions()` but in my feeling this is a less than ideal situation.

Comment: Have you take a look at http://octobercms.com/docs/backend/relations#belongs-to-many-pivot?

Comment: But it doens't belong to many. It only belongs to one. I have a temp fix via a dropdownlist I populate myself. The annoying thing is that it saves by id if I use a default octobercms relation field. I want it to save it as a string, different than the default primary key.

Comment: If you want to change the type of the field, it's via the `version.yaml` file. Drop the actuall collum, add a new one with the good type, and add the file to `version.yaml`. See (this)[https://github.com/rainlab/blog-plugin/blob/master/updates/create_posts_content_html.php#L9-24].

Comment: No, I am not at liberty to drop the primary key column. The column I want to use is unique, but not a suitable replacement for primary key. Plus the primary key is used in different places.I just want to store the key 'currencyISO' instead of $primaryKey in the other table row as the relation lookup thing.. Thats all I want to do. i do not want to break my database structure on which multiple applications are dependant.

Comment: A big problem that I saw with October, is that we can't edit database, without loosing DB content. I don't think that you can do that.

Comment: heck, did you really think i'd depend on october to modify my database? I'm making a special application not meant for redistribution. and you don't seem to understand what I want to achieve. What I want to achieve does not involve database modfiication in any way. That would be breaking down a wall to build a chair.